# Call a javascript handler with parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, handler

I have a method that calls another method (on ajax load, but that's irrelevant for this question). I'd like to pass parameters to this method. How is this possible?

The below page should scroll to id 25 on button click (the scrollable area is dynamically added in codebehind. this is just an example of what I'm attempting to accomplish)

JS

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="APTEIT.scrolltest" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callHandler(handler) {
        handler();
    }
    function scroll(id) {
        alert("scrolling");
        $("#divy").scrollTop($("#"+id).position().top);
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="scroll" onclick='var scroll={param1: "25"};callHandler(scroll)' />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not just pass the param directly into scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to pass the parameter into the handler in the `callHandler` method - instead, you try to invoke the `scroll` parameter (which is `var scroll={param1: "25"}`) as a function.

You use the same name `scroll` both for a config object and a function name. Please use different names :) Moreover, your declared and used function signatures do not agree. The `scroll` function accepts a string `id` while you are trying to pass in an object instead.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I found the function.apply method that takes a parameter array. I think that may work well in my case using the array of params and the handler, as you stated.

Comment: Right, but be careful with `apply` as it needs the _receiver_ argument as the first parameter. That might be an issue if you don't know anything about the nature of the callback you have in the general case. You will need to set it to `null` in your particular case.

Comment: I used 'this' and it worked fine. I've seen it used with 'this' and 'null' in my research, so I'd suppose my context works fine with 'this'

Comment: That's right. Passing in `null` effectively assigns `window` as the receiver, so these `null` and `this` and `window` in this case will work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

put the parameters into an object like so:

```
var handler = {
  param1: 'val1',
  param2: 'val2' //ect...
}

handler(handler);
```

**EDIT:**

changing:

```
$("#divy").scrollTop($("#"+id).position().top);
```

to:

```
$("#divy").scrollTop($("#"+id.param1).position().top);
```

should work for your edited question.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work for me. I'm getting a javascript no object found error. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

### Update 1

I think what you might be able to do in this instance is the use the `this` keyword in the context of the `input` element. What this will ultimately do in your instance is replace `id` with `this`. This will also remove the additional select. Try this:

```
function callHandler(handler)
{
    handler();
}

function scroll()
{
    $("#divy").scrollTop($(this).position().top);
}
```

`this` might not work, as I'm not sure if the context will be that of `input`, or `callHandler`, give it a go! :)

### Original

You should just be able to pass the parameters into the handler like so:

```
function callHandler(handler)
{
    var param = 'Hello world';
    handler(param);
}

callHandler(function(phrase)
{
    alert(phrase); 
});
```

Comment: I've updated what I'm looking for. It's more dynamic parameter passing. Perhaps I wasn't clear to start. See the edits above.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I think the context of `this` should be sufficient for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood, if `handler` is a `function` then pass arguments to it like any normal scenario.

```
function callHandler(handler){
   var passme = "test";
   handler(passme);
}
```

Comment: I've updated what I'm looking for. It's more dynamic parameter passing. Perhaps I wasn't clear to start. See the edits above.